# Is there any well done and automatic staking contract?

Tags: solidity, defi, staking

Staking contracts in Solidity are sometimes challenging to program, and it's even harder when you want to make them autonomous.

I would like to make a staking contract collecting fees from a defi protocol and distributing them to everybody staking tokens in the pool.

The issue is that those distribution would be at a different time intervals with various amounts each time.

Do any of you has examples of protocols who have deployed these kind of contracts ? I don't really like the idea of a private entity collecting the fees and sending a transaction to add rewards for a duration, as the most popular contracts did.